# How to use an input value with repetition operator?

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

How I can use a design input with the repetition operator in a SV assertion?
Basically, what I'm trying to implement is:

```
property ( ( disable iff((a) or (b) or (c) or (d))
          $rose(req) |-> req[*32]
```

I'm trying to replace the `32` with *t_req*, which is an input to the design module and can be changed by the user.

Is there any way to make the assertion dynamic so that the value *32* is not hardcoded?

Comment: See http://systemverilog.us/vf/SolvingComplexUsersAssertions.pdf

Comment: Is t_req a hardware signal or are you just looking to change the literal value in different places? If it's the latter, you could wrap the property in a macro function

Answer (score 0):

One way is to count how long `req` is high for and then to compare that with `t_req`. To do that, you need to embed some code inside your assertion. You can do that using this operator:

```
( <a sequence>, <some code>, <some more code>, ...)
```

When the sequence matches, the code is executed. You cannot write any code. There are only 3 things you can do:

- assign to a local variable
- increment/decrement a local variable
- call a function or task

A *local variable* is one declared within the property. The function or task must not assign to any other variables.

So, here is a suggestion:

```
property req_check;
    int unsigned pulse_width;
    ($rose(req), pulse_width=0) |-> (req, pulse_width++) ##1 (!req && check(pulse_width) );
endproperty

assert property ( disable iff ((a) or (b) or (c) or (d)) req_check);

function bit check(int unsigned width);
    return (width == t_req);
endfunction
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, because you didn't post a [mcve].  You're more likely to get good responses if you do.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this method.  Basically what I'm trying to implement is "The request should remain high for t_req clock cycles"

Comment: See also http://systemverilog.us/vf/SolvingComplexUsersAssertions.pdf